# Unnest elements of each object in Trino/Presto

Tags: sql, json, presto, trino, unnest

I have a column called **users** with this JSON.

```
{
"magda@email.com":[1.0,5.95],
"avsar@email.com":[2.0,30.733],
"fernandes@email.com":[1.0,4.433],
"amado@email.com":[2.0,16.25]
}
```

I want to unwrap it in this way

> | splitUsers | firstValue | secondValue |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | magda@email.com | 1.0 | 5.95 |
> | avsar@email.com | 2.0 | 30.733 |
> | fernandes@email.com | 1.2 | 4.433 |
> | amado@email.com | 2.0 | 16.25 |

I managed to split the emails with query below, however I can't get the array values as in seperate columns.

```
select * from tableName 
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(array_join(map_keys(CAST(json_parse(users) AS MAP(VARCHAR, JSON))),  ', '),',')) 
AS t (splitUsers)
```

Is there a way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be very close, one of the options would be using json extract functions (for example [`json_extract_scalar`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json_extract_scalar)) on the unnested value (after casting to `map`, note the succinct syntax for the `unnest`):

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset (users) as (
    values ('{
        "magda@email.com":[1.0,5.95],
        "avsar@email.com":[2.0,30.733],
        "fernandes@email.com":[1.0,4.433],
        "amado@email.com":[2.0,16.25]
    }')
)

-- query
select k splitUsers,
    json_extract_scalar(v, '$[0]') firstValue,
    json_extract_scalar(v, '$[1]') secondValue
from dataset
, unnest (cast(json_parse(users) as map(varchar, json))) as t(k,v)
;
```

Output:

| splitUsers | firstValue | secondValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| amado@email.com | 2.0 | 16.25 |
| avsar@email.com | 2.0 | 30.733 |
| fernandes@email.com | 1.0 | 4.433 |
| magda@email.com | 1.0 | 5.95 |

Answer (score 0):

You need to first unnest the map into separate rows, then extract out of the JSON array

```
SELECT
  tn.*,
  t.splitUsers,
  json_extract_scalar(t.vals, '$[0]') AS firstValue,
  json_extract_scalar(t.vals, '$[1]') AS secondValue
from tableName AS tn
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(CAST(json_parse(users) AS MAP(VARCHAR, JSON))) AS t (splitUsers, vals);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that builds on previous answers but avoids having to use `json_extract_scalar`.

It relies on the fact that in Trino you can cast a JSON object to a SQL map, and a JSON array to a SQL row: `CAST(json_parse(users) AS map(varchar, row(double, double)))`

```
WITH dataset(users) AS (
    VALUES ('{
        "magda@email.com":[1.0,5.95],
        "avsar@email.com":[2.0,30.733],
        "fernandes@email.com":[1.0,4.433],
        "amado@email.com":[2.0,16.25]
    }')
)

SELECT
    k AS splitUsers,
    v[1] AS firstValue,
    v[2] AS secondValue
FROM 
    dataset, 
    UNNEST(cast(json_parse(users) as map(varchar, row(double, double)))) as t(k,v)
```

In the latest version of Trino, you can use `JSON_TABLE` to process the data directly and extract the fields without having to call `json_parse` or convert the JSON values to a SQL type:

```
WITH dataset(users) AS ( ... )
SELECT t.*
FROM dataset, JSON_TABLE(users, 'strict $.keyvalue()' COLUMNS (
    splitUsers VARCHAR PATH 'strict $.name',
    firstValue DOUBLE PATH 'strict $.value[0]',
    secondValue DOUBLE PATH 'strict $.value[1]'
)) AS t
```